# BlazorStrap issue with Placeholder

Tags: blazor, placeholder

I have a problem with Placeholder in BlazorStrap.

It will not work if i have a property connected to my Value.

```
> <BSBasicInput Value="Test" PlaceHolder="Hello">
> 
> 
> public decimal Test { get; set; }
```

I have tried:

```
    > <BSBasicInput Value="string.Empty" PlaceHolder="Hello">
    > 
    > 
    >
```

If i take away the property and write "string.Empty" into the Value field i can the text from the placeholder.

How do i solve this so i can have a property to my Value in Input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property "Value" works as bind-Value In BlazorStrap. 
Placeholder works when value is empty(or null), but for default  field(Test) of decimal returns 0, not null, so this value shows in input.

You can compare this code:

```
<BSBasicForm>
    <BSFormGroup>
        <BSBasicInput InputType="InputType.Number" Value="@Test" PlaceHolder="Hello"></BSBasicInput>
    </BSFormGroup>
</BSBasicForm>

@code{
    public decimal? Test=null;
}
```